# JS: exit after completion async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have promises array and trying to make script exit after its execution:

```js
Promise.all([promises_array])
  .then(log.add('ok')
  .create())
  .catch(log.add('fail')
  .create())
  .then(process.exit(0));
```

but script finish immediately. How should I do this properly?

Comment: the problem might be in your log class. Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all , then change the `console.log` with your `log.add().create()` and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in an async function and `await Promise.all`

```
async function myFunc() {
  try{
    await Promise.all([promises_array]);
    log.add('ok').create();
  } catch() {
    log.add('fail').create();
  }
  process.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but my promises are not execute. App close without waiting for promises completion

Comment: Is it possible that your promises are instantly resolved or not actually async?